# How can I aggregate when I'm mapping in KnockoutJS?

Tags: json, rest, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm working with KnockoutJS for a few days now and I have just faced with a simple problem that I cannot solve!
I have a model like this:

```
function Contact() {
        var self = this;
        self.name = ko.observable("");
        self.phones = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.faxes = ko.observableArray([]);
        self.address = ko.observable("");
}
```

I have to call a service which will return repeatitive rows if each contact contains more that one phone or fax. e.g. :

```
{{"name":"Name1","phone":"1234","fax":"5654","address":"abc"},{{"name":"Name1","phone":"2323","fax":"8787","address":"abc"}}
```

I do a call like to server like this:

```
self.GetContacts = function () {
        $.getJSON(self.queryUrl(),
        function (data) {
            if (data.results) {
                self.contacts(ko.toJS(data.results));
            }
        });
```

There is no way to aggregate it on the serverside as it is an out-of-the-box tool and the only possible way is to aggregate it on the client side.

How can I aggregate them using my custom model, before binding them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like that :

```
function aggragateContacts(data) {
    var contacts = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function (contactData) {
        // looking an existing contact with the same name and address
        var contact = ko.utils.arrayFirst(contacts, function (c) {
            return c.name() == contactData.name && c.address() == contactData.address;
        });
        // otherwise create one 
        if (contact == null) {
            contact = new Contact();
            contact.name(contactData.name);
            contact.address(contactData.address);
            contacts.push(contact);
        }
        contact.phones.push(contactData.phone);
        contact.fax.push(contactData.fax);
    });
}


self.GetContacts = function () {
    $.getJSON(self.queryUrl(),

    function (data) {
        if (data.results) {
            self.contacts(aggragateContacts(ko.toJS(data.results)));
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Looks like there are many hidden treasures in KnockoutJS. Welldone Damien! I'm going to try it rightaway!